# CKEditor does not focus on iOS when tapping in text area

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, ckeditor, mobile-safari

CKEditor 4.0.1 is failing to focus when tapping in the text area on iOS 6.1 Safari. This happens both on the iphone and ipad (both running iOS 6.1). I can eventually get it to focus by tapping it several times. Sometimes it takes 5 taps, sometimes it takes 10 or 15. If I click the bold button, it focuses right away. Any ideas? Is there a way for me to manually capture the tap event and then call something that will focus the editor? I'm using jquery.

Comment: Ahh... I just inspected the contents iframe and found that the height is only 1 line tall... in other words, the iframe doesn't span the height of the content area. In order to focus, you need to make sure to tap at the very top of the content area. I wonder if there's an easy way to make the iframe height match the height of the content area.

Comment: I'm guessing that adding html{height:100%;} to the css for the ckeditor iframe might do the trick. But I'm not sure where I would make that change.

Comment: I was able to change the height of the html element from within my editor area css file, and verified that the height of the iframe does span the height of the content area. But this does not solve the problem. Setting the body to have a min-height of 100px does make it easier to focus the editor, but is obviously only a temporary fix that doesn't completely fix the problem.

Comment: Can you create a test case online? I tested Official CKEditor-4.0.1, it worked fine on IOS 6.1

Comment: http://testing.musiclessons.com/forum/test.cfm - when I view it on my iphone or ipad, you have to click in the very top part of the editor content area. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `height:100%;` to `HTML` and `BODY` elements in editor-test.css will fix this issue.
Final code will be like this:

```
html {height:100%;}
body {
    font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px; 
    line-height:1.4em;
    color: #333; 
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: The side effect of making that change is that the editor will always have a scrollbar. This is because the iframe content has a margin, so 100% plus the margin will always be taller than the viewport. My fix was to add min-height:250px (or whatever the initial height of the editor is when it's first viewed) to the body element.

Comment: I have set the height to 100% but still it's not working for me on iphone. any other solution?

Comment: Have you set it for both HTML and BODY tags? Can you paste your code to jsfiddle and share it here?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I ran up against this recently.

In the `ckeditor` folder I edited the `contents.css` file.  (It styles the contents of the editor)

In the `body` section, I added:

```
body 
{
    /* [other code is left as found] */

    /* Add the line below  */
    min-height: calc( 100% - 40px );
}
```

This takes into account differing custom heights defined in config.js and the `margin: 20px` declaration (which seems to be default).